# Can't move the png images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can't move the .png images from the desktop to resources folder it gives an alert.
Any help Please.

Comment: This question is very difficult to answer without a description of the error.

Comment: There is always an alert that asks if you want to copy it or just make a reference. If this is not the alert you are looking at, then you need to give more details like @Alex mentioned.

Comment: Alex, I was trying to move some .png images, which are on my desktop to the resources folder but I get an alert saying that "you can't move xxx.png" with an alert dialog

Comment: Hey Ryan, after that reference alert i get another dialog saying can't move the .png.

Comment: @Alex and @Ryan..Thanks got it I don't know y der was a alert..its good now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any files in the resources folder that have the same filename. Somethimes Xcode can't overwrite these.